# Show active sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

So I'm trying to not show a side bar if it there are no widgets to show

when I use the `is_active_sidebar()` function it always returns false and the if statement doesn't work and when I try to use the `is_dynamic_sidebar()` function it always returns true.

I have the widget logic plugin installed so some of the widgets show up on a page and some pages don't have a widget.

This is my code:

```
        <div class="row main-row">
        <?php if (is_dynamic_sidebar('left_bar')) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 left-sidebar">
                <?php
                dynamic_sidebar('left_bar');
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9 main-content">
                <?php the_content('Read More'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="col-md-12 main-content">
                <?php the_content('Read More'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Any Ideas on what should I do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong function for checking active sidebar try this

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left_bar' ) )
dynamic_sidebar( 'left_bar' );
```

Comment: When I use the is_active_sidebar('left_bar') function it results in not showing the sidebar even for the pages that have a sidebar

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it is different way of using sidebar

[1] put your all "left_bar"(sidebar) code in a new file named "sidebar-left_bar"

[2] save it with header.php, function.php and all files

[3] now just use `<?php get_sidebar( 'left_bar' ); ?>` where you want to use

Thanks

Comment: should I add the if statement inside that file or just the part between curly brackets?

Comment: mno you dont need to put if statement inside file, just follow step 3 , where ever you want to use that as sidebar.

Comment: I changed the file as you instructed and still no luck. The page behaves exactly as it used to.
Code for the sidebar-left_bar.php :

`<div class="col-md-3 left-sidebar">
 <?php
 dynamic_sidebar('left_bar');
 ?>
</div>`


Pages code:
`<div class="row main-row">
 <?php if (is_dynamic_sidebar( 'left_bar' )) { ?>
  <?php get_sidebar( 'left_bar' ); ?>    
  <div class="col-md-9 main-content">
  <?php the_content('Read More'); ?>
  </div>
 <?php } else { ?>
  <div class="col-md-12 main-content">
  <?php the_content('Read More'); ?>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
</div>`

Comment: you have to change the condition of  is_dynamic_sidebar('left_bar') && <?php dynamic_sidebar('left_bar'); ?> cause now it will not work as more. use simply <?php get_sidebar( 'left_bar' ); ?> where you want, it will display.

Comment: The problem is not displaying the sidebar it is using an if statement to see if there is a sidebar to be shown or not. because if there is none I have to show a bigger main-content div